# Customizing of bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart with the data below.

```
library(plotly)
    df_t<-data.frame(
                      Country=c('Aruba','Armenia','Albania','Bahami','Bhutan','Benin','Aruba','Armenia','Albania','Bahami','Bhutan','Benin'),
                      Year=c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011),
                      Male=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10),
                      Female=c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10))
```

Now I want to make a chart with Plotly library and I tried with this line of code:

```
Chart <- plot_ly(df_t, x = ~Year, y = ~Country, name = "Aruba", type = 'bar', mode = 'lines',  
                  line = list(dash = "solid"))
```

But this is not what I need to have. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and produce chart as chart showed below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

General approach for a plotly stacked bar chart from https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/

```
    fig <- plot_ly(df_t, x = ~Country, y = ~Male, type = 'bar', name = 'Male')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Female, name = 'Female')
    fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
    
    fig
```

This still requires refinement to convert to a percentage scale, add the additional x category etc but should get you started.